# mysql Group by today

Tags: mysql

Hello I would like to spend over mysql only all data with today's date. Unfortunately there is only GROUP BY YEAR and MONTH

```
SELECT rechnung.*, re_kunden.*,  SUM(re_kunden.gpreis) as preise 
FROM rechnung
    LEFT JOIN re_kunden ON rechnung.ID = re_kunden.ID_rechnung
WHERE rechnung.ID LIKE re_kunden.ID_rechnung
GROUP BY ???TODAY???(rechnung.datum)
```

Data

```
+----+-------------+----------+------------+-------------+---------+
| ID | rechnungsnr | kundennr |   datum    | lieferdatum | bezahlt |
+----+-------------+----------+------------+-------------+---------+
| 10 |       10010 |     1003 | 2018-12-09 | 2018-12-10  |       1 |
| 11 |       10009 |     1005 | 2018-12-09 | 2018-12-10  |       1 |
| 12 |       10011 |     1001 | 2018-12-10 | 2018-12-10  |       1 |
| 13 |       10054 |     1004 | 2018-12-10 | 2018-12-10  |       1 |
+----+-------------+----------+------------+-------------+---------+
```

and Data

```
+----+-------------+----------+-------------+-------+----------+--------+--------+------+
| ID | ID_rechnung | position | bezeichnung | menge | einheit  | epreis | gpreis | text |
+----+-------------+----------+-------------+-------+----------+--------+--------+------+
|  1 |          10 |        1 | text        |     1 | text     |      1 |      1 | text |
|  2 |          11 |        1 | text        |     2 | text     |      1 |      2 | text |
|  3 |          12 |        1 | text        |     3 | text     |      1 |      3 | text |
|  4 |          13 |        1 | text        |     1 | text     |      1 |      1 | text |
+----+-------------+----------+-------------+-------+----------+--------+--------+------+
```

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: If you are only selecting data for today ___(which you are not)___ what would be the point in grouping on that date as they will all be the same date

Comment: `WHERE rechnung.ID LIKE re_kunden.ID_rechnung` You already did a JOIN on these 2 fields so this is nonsense

Comment: How much [research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: yeah its correct WHERE rechnung.ID LIKE re_kunden.ID_rechnung doesnt need. 
I searched for a solution for more than a few minutes. Unfortunately I have probably had a mistake somewhere in the code, which is why I have now asked for a solution here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try  rechnung.datum = curdate() in WHERE clause rather GROUP BY since you only need records of today.

```
  SELECT rechnung.*, re_kunden.*,  SUM(re_kunden.gpreis) as preise 
  FROM rechnung
     LEFT JOIN re_kunden ON rechnung.ID = re_kunden.ID_rechnung
     WHERE rechnung.ID LIKE re_kunden.ID_rechnung
     AND rechnung.datum = curdate()
```

Comment: Welcome, Enjoy Coding!